# How important is a router for piVPN

Tags: vpn, owncloud

I have setup piVPN , ownCLoud and Plex on raspberry pi. I know Plex is over kill and pi struggles with it.

Mostly I am not concerned with Plex but piVPN and ownCloud.

While they seem to work OK with my ISP default router ([sagemcom F@ST4315U](http://www.sagemcom.com/broadband/gateways/dsl-gateways/fst-4315/)), I am thinking will an router upgrade really impact the performance.

To set the context of the question for VPN and PI, I am excluding gaming (not into) and streaming details.

Comment: Is the VPN primarily used within your LAN?  If not, why do you believe buying another router will make any difference?

Comment: @goldilocks, VPN is being used from outside. But I experience a lag and thinking if it's due to routers limited capacity to process multiple requests when( 4 Clients connected, 1 VPN request, 1 Owncloud request, 1 request for Samba Share) .. not sure though.